# Set response code in rest control

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I can't figure out how to set response code in my REST control element.

[image]

Here is the code of REST control.

```
    <xe:restService id="restProfile" pathInfo="profile">
    <xe:this.service>
        <xe:customRestService
            doGet="#{javascript:REST_PROFILE.doGet()}"
            contentType="application/json"
            doPost="#{javascript:REST_PROFILE.doPost(reqVar)}"
            requestContentType="application/json" requestVar="reqVar">
        </xe:customRestService>
    </xe:this.service>
</xe:restService>
```

The requirement is to return code 404 in some cases and I can't find out how to do it.

Does anybody know how to do it using SSJS?

Version of Domino is 9.0.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't return a status 404 with doGet and doPost. The response property status is managed by the customRestService. The SSJS code can return JSON data only.
You might define your own JSON content like

```json
{
    "status": "error",
    "error-message": "something not found"
}
```

though and handle errors this way.

As an alternative you can use customRestService's **serviceBean**.

```xml
        <xe:customRestService
            contentType="application/json"
            requestContentType="application/json"
            serviceBean="de.leonso.demo.RestService">
        </xe:customRestService>
```

and set return code with `response.setStatus(status)` there:

```java
public class RestService extends CustomServiceBean {
    @Override
    public void renderService(CustomService service, RestServiceEngine engine) throws ServiceException {
        try {
            HttpServletRequest request = engine.getHttpRequest();
            HttpServletResponse response = engine.getHttpResponse();
            response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");

            String method = request.getMethod();
            int status = 200;
            if (method.equals("GET")) {
                status = ...
            } else {
                ...
            }
            response.setStatus(status);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Knut.
I will accept it as an answer as it is 'one in one' what I suspected.